# Does Observable.Zip() on two observables wait for a pair to complete?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming, observable

Say we have two hot observables of integers,
and we get a resulting one like this

```
var result = Observable.Zip(observable1, observable2);
```

My question is, say an element comes through observable1, does the result wait for a matching pair in observable2 before calling observer or it takes the last value from observer2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zip waits for a pair to come through.

If you want to use the latest value from `observer2` when a value comes through `observable1`, you should use [CombineLatest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211991%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).

You can also find more info on combining sequences in the Intro to Rx [chapter on that topic](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/12_CombiningSequences.html).